# this keyword and the game state

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at the Phaser game framework and cannot work out what the **this** keyword refers to.

For example if I console log 'this' it displays the object **MyGame.StateB** . However, if I replace the this keyword with MyGame.StateB, e.g. 
**MyGame.StateB.background** , the application throws an error. Can anyone explain my lack of understanding?

```
MyGame.StateB = function (game) {

    this.background;
    this.girls;


};

MyGame.StateB.prototype = {

    create: function () {

        this.background = this.add.sprite(0, 150, 'background');

        this.girls = this.add.sprite(0, 150, 'anizeen');
        console.log(this); // MyGame.StateB 
        var tween = this.add.tween(this.background).to( { x: -800 }, 8000, "Linear", true, 0, -1, true);
    }

};
```

Comment: How are you calling the `create` function?

Comment: what does the error say? Should help you understand...error messages are very informative

Comment: The create function is called when stateB is started  (game.state.add('StateB', MyGame.StateB);). The error is - 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment'

Comment: so now did you research that error? Also doesn't seem to be the code you have shown

Comment: The console is telling you that *this* is an instance of *MyGame.StateB*, not that is **is** *MyGame.StateB*. Consoles try to be helpful, sometimes they are confusing to the point of misleading.

Answer (score 1):

> if I console log 'this' it displays the object MyGame.StateB"

I think you are getting confused by how the console "names" objects. Look at the following example:

[image]

Even though logging `f` displays `Foo {}`, that doesn't mean that `f` is the same `Foo`, as you can see by the result of `f === Foo`. The console simply tries to give the object referenced by `f` a "name". You have to read this as "the object is *of type* `Foo`" or "the object was *constructed by* `Foo`".

So in your code, `this` refers to an object that was *constructed* by `MyGame.StateB`. `MyGame.StateB` was called, a new object was created and returned. `background` is a property of *that* object, not of `MyGame.StateB` itself. Therefore, `MyGame.StateB.background` is `undefined`.

---

So, since `this` and `MyGame.StateB` are not equivalent, it doesn't make sense to substitute them.

I recommend to read [YDKJS - this & Object prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/93abe1810e84253ed46535120a3c62a8e309edda/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes) to learn more about how `this`, prototypes and constructors related to each other and how they work.